# Is there a way to create copies of variables so that the original variables don't change in a function?

Tags: c, function, scope, cs50

i'm currently working on a substitution problem in CS50 , and i have a problem with the way my variables behaves in the code.
basically i got the two variables plain_text and key_2. my problem is that those 2 variables, despite the fact that i'm creating copies of them so they won't change, keep getting assigned the values their copies get. now i know it's related someway to the scopes of the variables, but i just can't figure out how to do it correctly so on the copies of the variables change and not the originals.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

string substitute_strings (string plain_text,string key);

int main (int argc, string argv[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {

        if (argc == 1)
        {
            printf ("Enter key!\n");
            return 1;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen (argv[1]); j++)
        {
            if ((argv[1][j] >= 'a' && argv[1][j] <= 'z') || (argv[1][j] >= 'A' && argv[1][j] <= 'Z'))
            {
                int var = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                printf ("Key can contain only alphabet!");
                return 1;

            }

             }
              if (strlen(argv[1]) != 26)
        {

            printf ("Key must contain 26 characters!\n");
            return 1;

        }

        for (int c = 0; c < strlen (argv[1]); c++)
        {
            for (int b = c + 1; b < strlen (argv[1]);b++)
            {
                if (argv[1][c] == argv[1][b])
                {
                    printf ("Character cannot repeat twice in key!");
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
                                    }

string key = argv[1];

string plain_text = get_string ("Enter messege here: \n");



printf("ciphertext: %s\n",substitute_strings (string plain_text , string key));
return 0;
}


**string substitute_strings (string plain,string key_2)**


    {

        string alphabet_upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        string alphabet_lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

      
        string plain_copy = plain;
        

        for (int m = 0; m < strlen (plain_copy); m++)
    {
        if (plain_copy[m] >= 'A' && plain_copy[m] <= 'Z')
        {
            int exit_loop = 0;
            for (int n = 0; exit_loop < 1;n++)
            {
                if (alphabet_upper[n] == plain_copy[m])
                {
                    plain_copy[m] = key_2[n];
                    exit_loop++;
                }
            }
        }

        else if (plain_copy[m] >= 'a' && plain_copy[m] <= 'z')
        {
            int h = 0;
            string key_2_copy = key_2;
            
            while (h < strlen (key_2))
            {
            key_2_copy[h] = tolower(key_2_copy[h]);
            h++;

            }

            int exit_loop_2 = 0;
            int p = 0;
            while (exit_loop_2 < 1)
            {
                if (alphabet_lower [p] == plain_copy [m])
                {
                    plain_copy[m] = key_2_copy [p];
                    exit_loop_2++;
                }
                p++;}





    }
    }


return plain_copy;


}
```

Comment: It looks like the indentation of the code got a little messed up when you tried to increase it to format this question. You can display code without the extra indentation by using three "backtick" marks (`) on the line before your block of code and on the line after.

Comment: This is a great example of "Why hiding pointers with typedefs is a bad idea".

Comment: Good news: `strdup()` will, very probably, be part of the next published C standard (see [C2x draft (PDF document)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2478.pdf))

Comment: the posted code does not compile!   When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.   (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results.

Comment: regarding statements like; `printf("ciphertext: %s\n",substitute_strings (string plain_text , string key));`  when calling a function do not include the parameter types.  The only time(s) the parameter types are needed is in a prototype and in the function signature.  Therefore the statement should be:  `printf( "ciphertext: %s\n", substitute_strings ( plain_text , key ) );`  Note the horizontal spacing for readability by us humans

Answer (score 4):

`string` in context of cs50 is an alias to `char*` and the pointers are actually copied.

To copy the pointed strings, you should allocate a memory and use `strcpy()`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

should be added at the top of code to use `malloc()` (and `exit()`) and

```
string plain_copy = plain;
```

should be

```
string plain_copy = malloc(strlen(plain) + 1); /* +1 for terminating null-character */
if (plain_copy == NULL) { /* check if allocation is successful */
    perror("malloc");
    exit(1);
}
strcpy(plain_copy, plain);
```

Answer (score 2):

The CS50 library is setting you up for failure here because it grossly misrepresents how strings are handled in C. In short, the `string` typedef name is a lie, because what it aliases is **not a string**.  Get comfortable, this will take a while.

First, some necessary background...

C does not have a real string data type with its own semantics and operators - in C, a string is simply a sequence of character values including a 0-valued terminator, so a string like `"foo"` is represented as the sequence `'f', 'o', 'o', 0`.  Strings are stored in arrays of character type (`char` or `wchar_t` for "wide" character encodings), but you can also store sequences of characters that are *not* strings (they don't have the 0 terminator) in arrays of character type.

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted, or "decay" to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the string.  Among other things, this means that when you pass an array expression to a function, what the function actually receives is a pointer to the first element of the array:

```
void foo( char *str )
{
   // do something with str
}

int main( void )
{
  char string[] = "hello";  // array size is taken from length of string + 1

  foo( string ); 
  ...
}
```

What we get in memory is something like this:

```
        +---+
   str: |   |---------------+
        +---+               |
         ...                |
        +---+               |
string: |'h'| string[0] <---+
        +---+
        |'e'| string[1]
        +---+
        |'l'| string[2]
        +---+
        |'l'| string[3]
        +---+
        |'o'| string[4]
        +---+
        | 0 | string[5]
        +---+
```

`str` doesn't contain the string itself, it contains the address of the buffer where the string is stored.  This behavior is the same for *all* array types, not just arrays containing strings.

The upshot of this is that when we're dealing with strings, most of the time we're dealing with expressions of type `char *`.  But a `char *` **is not a string** - it *may* point to the first character of a string, or it may point to the first character of a sequence that isn't a string (no terminator), or it may point to a single `char` object that isn't part of a larger sequence.

Okay, that's the background.  So how does all that apply to your code?

The CS50 library performs all kinds of magic under the hood to isolate you from the gory details of I/O and memory management.  The `get_string` function prompts the user for input, *dynamically* allocates memory to store the input string, and returns a *pointer* to that dynamic buffer:

```
char *str = malloc( SOME_SIZE );
// get string from input and save to this buffer
return str;
```

The CS50 library introduces the typedef name `string` as an alias for the type `char *`.  This means objects of type `string` are actually *pointers*, not strings.

So when you assign the result of `get_string` to `plain_text`, what you have in memory is something like this (assume `"foo"` was the input):

```
            +---+
plain_text: |   | ----+
            +---+     |
             ...      |
            +---+     |
            |'f'| <---+
            +---+
            |'o'|
            +---+
            |'o'|
            +---+
            | 0 | <-- string terminator
            +---+
```

So `plain_text` doesn't store the string itself, it stores the *address* of the buffer containing the string.  When you pass `plain_text` to `substitute_strings`, it's just receiving this pointer value, not a copy of the string.

When you write

```
plain_copy = plain;
```

you are copying the *address* of the buffer into `plain_copy`, so both `plain` *and* `plain_copy` are pointing to the *same memory*:

```
            +---+
plain_copy: |   | -------+
            +---+        |
             ...         |
            +---+        |
     plain: |   | ----+  |
            +---+     |  |
             ...      |  |
            +---+     |  |
            |'f'| <---+--+
            +---+
            |'o'|
            +---+
            |'o'|
            +---+
            | 0 |
            +---+
```

Any change you make to the buffer is reflected in both `plain` and `plain_copy`.

So how do you get around this?

In your `substitute_strings` function, you will need to allocate a second buffer of the same size and assign its address to `plain_copy`, then copy the contents of `plain` into that new buffer:

```
string plain_copy = malloc( strlen( plain ) + 1 );
if ( plain_copy )
  strcpy( plain_copy, plain );
else
  // unable to allocate memory for copy, handle as appropriate

// manipulate and return plain_copy as before
```

Now you have the following situation:

```
            +---+
     plain: |   | ----+
            +---+     |
             ...      |
            +---+     |
            |'f'| <---+
            +---+
            |'o'|
            +---+
            |'o'|
            +---+
            | 0 |
            +---+

            +---+
plain_copy: |   | ----+
            +---+     |
             ...      |
            +---+     |
            |'f'| <---+
            +---+
            |'o'|
            +---+
            |'o'|
            +---+
            | 0 |
            +---+
```

`plain` and `plain_copy` point to two different strings now, so changes to one don't affect the other.